# How can I get number of rows and columns selected by excel COM interface?

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32, pyxll

I can get area selected by application's `.Selection` property.

(I'm using python to access excel com interface)

I want to know how many rows and columns user have selected, for instance

```
input:
    user has selected A1:G8
output:
    the selected range starts from Column 1 (by selection.Column)
    the selected range starts from Row 1 (by selection.Column)
    the selected range is spanning 7 rows (by ?)
    the selected range is spanning 8 columns (by ?)
```

I'm looking at MSDN's [Range interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms281150%28v=office.14%29.aspx), but the property's doesn't seems to be helpful for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From VBA, you could do something like this:

```
Debug.Print Selection.Rows.Count
Debug.Print Selection.Columns.Count
Debug.Print Selection.Row
Debug.Print Selection.Column
```

With A1:G8 selected, this returns

```
8 
7 
1 
1
```

Is that easily translated to Python>

Comment: thanks, `Selection.Rows.Count` and `Selection.Columns.Count` works.